# How do I override onBackPressed to ensure a logged out user cannot "go back" to MainActivity, and a logged in user cannot "go back" to SignInActivity?

Tags: java, android, authentication

Background: I have a SignInUserActivity and a MainActivity. The SignInUserActivity is first presented to the user when the user has not signed in or the auth token expired. On successful login, the user is directed to MainActivity, or if the auth token is valid on open of app the user will directed to MainActivity when the user opens the app. The user can sign out from MainActivity which will direct the user back to SignInUserActivity.

1) User signs in from SignInUserActivity. When user pressed onBackPressed in SignInUserActivity, the app should close (or move to background)>

2) After the user signs in, user should NOT be able to go back to the SignInUserActivity by onBackPressed enough times or navigateUp button on toolbar, onBackPressed should ONLY close the app (or move it to background). Currently, I have

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

in my MainActivity, yet

3) If the user signs out from MainActivity, in SignInUserActivity, onBackPressed should not direct the user back to MainActivity (with empty data since the session was already deleted). Currently the way I'm handling it is redirecting the user back to SignInUserActivity:

```
public void handleRedirect(String sessionId) {
    if (sessionId == null) {
        Intent requireSignInIntent = new Intent(this, SignInUserActivity.class);
        startActivity(requireSignInIntent);
    }
}
```

but instead it should be overriding onBackPressed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem can easily be resolved by starting a new `Activity` Stack. Just add this when you start `SignInActivity`and when you navigate to other `Activity` after a succefull log in

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

This flags should cover your 1st and 2nd problem. As for the 3rd problem, it seems you're doing the logic well but I didn't quite get that last part.

Comment: Did it help you ?